# simple wordpress author notify function

Tags: php, wordpress

hello there all fellow developers 
today i had a very strange and simple problem , i need to notify post authors when there posts are approved in WordPress site .. the strange thing when i use the following code in my theme functions it doesn't work only work's when i type the email variable manually .. thanks for your help

```
    function notify_new_post($post_id) {
   // if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' )  ) {
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $author_email = $author->user_email;
        // "x_123@windowslive.com";
        $email_subject = "Your post has been published.";

        ob_start(); ?>

        <html>
            <head>
                <title>New post at <?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>
                    Hi <?php echo $author->user_firstname ?>,
                </p>
                <p>
                    Your post <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>"><?php the_title_attribute() ?></a> has been published.
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>

        <?php

        $message = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        wp_mail( $author_email, $email_subject, $message );
        //    }
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'notify_new_post' ); ?>
```

Comment: forget to mention although that it doesn't get the user first name only leaves blank space .. thanks

Comment: Why did you comment `$_POST` section?

Comment: as i am still testing so in order to speed up a little bit the process i commented the if statement so i got the email sent when i set post statues  to waiting for review and published as well .. thanks

Comment: you can see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `transition_post_status` because

`This function's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers, but only in other core functions.`

in [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_transition_post_status) . You can use [publish_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) instead and your function needs a bit refactoring. And important point here, you are using custom pust type, so action name must be in a format like `publish_{custom_post_type_name}`;

```
<?php

function notify_new_post($post_id) {
   if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $author_email = $author->user_email;
        // "x_123@windowslive.com";
        $email_subject = "Your post has been published.";

        ob_start(); ?>

        <html>
            <head>
                <title>New post at <?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>
                    Hi <?php echo $author->user_firstname ?>,
                </p>
                <p>
                    Your post <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>"><?php the_title_attribute() ?></a> has been published.
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>

        <?php

        $message = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        wp_mail( $author_email, $email_subject, $message );
    }
}

add_action( 'publish_{custom_post_type_name}', 'notify_new_post', 100 ); // Increase priority 

?>
```

Comment: yeah that explains why it refused to declare the variables thanks a lot .. but the problem it's not working with publish_post hook that's why i changed it the first place , for some reason it didn't send anything

Comment: But I have just tested it. How do you test it? Open a post on admin panel change status as pending review and publish again. By the way, you need to put my code in `functions.php`

Comment: doesn't work the code is placed in functions.php , do you think s2 members ,bb and those sort of plugins might affect querying user email here ??

Comment: Maybe, my suggestion is put a `var_dump($POST);exit;` in start of function. If it is not printed, you need to increase priority of action as I stated in answer

Comment: added the var_dumb and increased piriorty to 100 and nothing shows up may be this hook isin't working with custom post type ??

Comment: Are you using custom post type? Which plugin do you use , I will test it on my side. And also, check your php error log to see any error exists

Comment: just tested it in regular posts and the var dumb showed up returning null .. now we are clear that it does'nt work with custom post types

Comment: i use custom post types registered on the functions.php

Comment: Ok then, you need to update action name like; `add_action( 'publish_{custom_post_type_name}', 'notify_new_post', 100 );`. We were using `publish_post` action but it must be `publish_book` if your custom post type name is `book` for example

Comment: amazing please add this as an answer so i accept it .. thank you so much

Comment: I have already added in my answer. And you can also update content of your question